# Why WPF datagrid CopyingCellClipboardContent will fire together

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am trying to copy a value of the a grid cell that I selected , therefore I add CopyingCellClipboardContent to all Datagrid column with different handler . but somehow I have no idea why all `CopyingCellClipboardContent` will be fire , because I just select 1 Cell. Will it be cause by the selectionUnit ?

For example , I select column2 , it show only fire `DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent_Col2` , instead it will fire `DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent_Col1`  as well.

Following is my datagrid code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdTest"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader"  >
<DataGrid.Columns>    
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Column1}" Width="*" CopyingCellClipboardContent="DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent_Col1">
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Column2}" Width="*" CopyingCellClipboardContent="DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent_Col2">
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: It is caused by SelectionUnit property of the Datagrid. By default SelectionUnit is FullRow, Hence CopyingCellClipboardContent will be triggered for both the cells. If you make SelectionUnit=Cell, then it will fired only for the selected cell.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian is that anyway not to achieve this without changing the selectionUnit ?